# $.ajax POST method not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
function callWebhookAndShowCart(element) {
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
        xhrFields: { 
            withCredentials: true 
        } 
    });
    var webHook = $(element).attr('webHook');
    var webParams = $(element).attr('webParams');

    if (webHook) {
        $.ajax({
            url: webHook,
            data: webParams,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(cart) {
                getCartRendering(cart);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However the following does not work and returns `method not allowed`:

```
function callWebhookAndShowCart(element) {
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
        xhrFields: { 
            withCredentials: true 
        } 
    });
    var webHook = $(element).attr('webHook');
    var webParams = $(element).attr('webParams');

    if (webHook) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webHook,
            data: webParams,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(cart) {
                getCartRendering(cart);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only change is converting from `GET` to `POST`. The server configuration as evident from the response header is:

```
Response Header
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, Content-Type, X-PINGOTHER, x-requested-by, Content-length, Connection
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 15 Dec 2016 08:39:03 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Please help as I am not sure what needs to be changed for the server configuration for this to work.

Comment: Could you paste the complete error message ? you're code isn't integrate between ", as you have use ' all over  ?

Comment: The domain itself can accept any type of request, however the endpoint you're calling only accepts GET

Comment: Check your `webparams` variable and also see if Post request is allowed to `webhook` or not (try posting a form to the `webhook`)

Comment: Thanks guys. Rory, the endpoint was not configured properly for POST. Thanks for your help. Its working now without any further changes.